# How to send SMS to mobile phone from java program- Using free APIs or WebServices

Tags: java, web-services, sms, sms-gateway

I need to write a program that should be able to send a text SMS to mobile phone through java programming. What i got to know so far is using SMS Gateways and connect modem with sim card.

But I cannot install SMS Gateways and modem on client machine. 
Can i use `smtp` host.

```
How can i use Web Service to send sms?
```

Your time and contribution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use a web service based SMS gateway, like twilio.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. Let me check this.

Comment: can you please give me some sample code if you have something. How use this in my java program.

Comment: Code posted in answer below... :)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. How to configure thin on my system. I mean do I need to download some jar from any where?

Comment: I modified my answer to include a link to the twilio library on github that the code uses.  You'll need to setup that.  There are some great walkthroughs out there with a quick google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the twilio SMS gateway, you can easily accomplish this.

```
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.factory.MessageFactory;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Message;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {

  // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/user/account
  public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "AC32a3c49700934481addd5ce1659f04d2";
  public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "{{ auth_token }}";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws TwilioRestException {
    TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    // Build a filter for the MessageList
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", "Abdul please?! I show you"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", "+14159352345"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "+14158141829"));

    MessageFactory messageFactory = client.getAccount().getMessageFactory();
    Message message = messageFactory.create(params);
    System.out.println(message.getSid());
  }
}
```

Here is a link to the twilio library: https://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install

Comment: Hi scott. Is this free?

Comment: The library is free and open source, but you will need a phone number to use it, which costs one dollar if you continue after their free trial.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hlep. Actually I need a way that should not have any constraints like I should have phone number and I should pay one dollar. After installing my app on client machine he will not agree with these conditions.

Comment: I can use smtp server..... Client can provide his smtp server details.